# How to compare arrays one by one with powershell

Tags: powershell

How to compare arrays one by one with powershell.

I have tried with eq/match/like/contains/in. But still not working fine. Thanks a lot.

input【array】:

$array = @('OK','OK','OK','OK')

$array1 = @('OK','failed','OK','OK')

$array2 = @("OK")

Expected output:

$Array compare Array2 output Ture

$Array1 compare Array2 output False

Comment: Why would `$array` having 4 elements compared to `$array2` having just one element compare `True` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the **order** of the elements (not only the values) of the two arrays matters (i.e. both arrays should have the same number of elements, the element values must be the same AND the order in which the elements appear should be the same), you can use

```
@(Compare-Object $array1 $array2 -SyncWindow 0).Length -eq 0
```

If the order in which the elements appear in the arrays doesn't matter:

```
@(Compare-Object $array1 $array2).Length -eq 0
```

---

**Edit**

Given your comment *"if all values are OK in array, then output true, If one of them is not OK, then output is false"*, you can simply do:

```
$array = 'OK','OK','OK','OK'
# test if all elements are 'OK'
($array | Where-Object { $_ -ne 'OK' }).Count -eq 0  # outputs True
```

If one of the elements is not 'OK', like with `$array1`

```
$array1 = 'OK','failed','OK','OK'
# test if all elements are 'OK'
($array1 | Where-Object { $_ -ne 'OK' }).Count -eq 0  # outputs False
```

<sup>The 'trick' here is that whe pipe the individual elements of the array to a `Where-Object` clause. That serves as a filter and lets all elements that are not 'OK' through. Finally, we just use the `Count` property of the resulting array and if there is nothing in there, the count will be 0, meaning `True`</sup>

Comment: While your solution does, in fact, use a more solid comparison technique for objects, it does not produce the "desired output" of the op.  Based on that desired output, I think the wording of the question led you to your suggestion even though the op didn't really want to compare the objects themselves, but the contents.

Comment: thanks in advance , sorry my English not very will and Maybe there's something wrong with my statement.

Comment: thank you for your answers , sorry my English not very will and Maybe there's something wrong with my statement.  my requirement is , if all values are OK  in array ,then output true,   If one of them is not OK , then output is false.

Comment: @bestsinger I have added new code to my answer, hopefully that can get you on your way. As you can see, there is no need for the `@()` when you create an array; just the values separated by a comma is enough.

Comment: You did me a big favor! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Theo elegant solution for this problem.  I may have to rewrite a bunch of my code at work.  Thank you very much for doubling my workload next week.  ;)

Comment: @Matthew Thanks and.. sorry for causing you extra work ;)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `Group-Object` would make this easier.

```
@($array+$array2 | Group-Object).Count -eq 1
True
@($array1+$array2 | Group-Object).Count -eq 1
False
```

If all input arrays contain the same element values, then it will return `True`.

The reason for the `@()` syntax is to always create an array with a `Count` property. This will override the `Count` property conflicts with `Group-Object` in cases where single objects are returned. If `Group-Object` only finds one variant (resulting in one object), then the output object will be a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo` object with its own `Count` property. When multiple objects are returned, the object type is `System.Object[]`, which has the `Count` property we are looking for.

---

Alternatively, [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) mentioned using the automatic property `Length`, which produces a slightly more concise solution. This solution is more obscure given the hidden nature of the `Length` property.

```
($array+$array2 | Group-Object).Length -eq 1
($array1+$array2 | Group-Object).Length -eq 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but  Theo's answer is more in line with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected output, I believe you are trying to determine if all elements of a source array (`$array and $array1` in your case) are equal to the value in a test array (`$array2` in your case).  I think I have a similar use case while moving data directories around my network.  My movement script creates a CSV as a log file, and it contains a column "Success" which indicates if each file copy was successful or not.  I have a routine which takes one of these log files as an input, and treats the "Success" column as an array of "True/False" values.  In order to see if the entire copy is valid, I have to determine that all of the "Success" elements for each individual file are "True" and boil that down into a single "True/False" for the entire copy.

If that is true, you would do the following:

```
$good = $true
$sourcearray | % {$good = $good -and ($_ -eq $testarray[0])}
```

If all elements of `$sourcearray` are equal to `$testarray[0]` then `$good` will remain `$true`.  So:

```
$array = @('OK','OK','OK','OK')
$array1 = @('OK','failed','OK','OK')
$array2 = @("OK")

$arraygood = $true
$array | % {$arraygood = $arraygood -and ($_ -eq $array2[0])}

$array1good = $true
$array1 | % {$array1good = $array1good -and ($_ -eq $array2[0])}

"`$arraygood = $arraygood"
"`$array1good = $array1good"
```

Running the above code gives me the results:

```
$arraygood = True
$array1good = False
```

I hope this helps.  If it does, please do not forget to accept the answer with the checkmark in the upper right.  Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your answers , sorry my English not very will and Maybe there's something wrong with my statement. my requirement is , if all values are OK in array ,then output true, If one of them is not OK , then output is false.

Comment: If that is the case, then I guessed right and my code should work for your use case.